# Loop Page Number in PHP

Tags: arrays, forms, url, printing

i have a question. And i hope you all can help me :D

So, this is it. I have form like this.

```
<form action="example.php" method="POST">
Page Count:<br />
<input type="text" name="page" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="View" />
</form>
```

And the example.php like this.

```
    <?php

    $page = $_POST['page'];

    $url = "http://example.org/page=".$page;

    echo $url;

    ?>
```

I want the url will show each page based on page count value. If page count value is 5, so the url with like this:

1. example.org/page=1
2. example.org/page=2
3. example.org/page=3
4. example.org/page=4
5. example.org/page=5

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a for loop in your php script like this:

```
<?php
  $page = $_POST['page'];
  for ($i=1; $i<=$page; $i++){
    $url = "http://example.org/page=".$i."<br/>";
    echo $url;
  }
?>
```

The output would look like this:

```
http://example.org/page=1
http://example.org/page=2
http://example.org/page=3
```